# Q Chaining Asynchronous

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, q

I have several arguments with my coworkers at this point over chaining asynchronous promises.  I say its not supported by Q, they say it is but cannot give me any valid answers.  Please maybe you guys can!

SO here is the problem: We have Asynchronous!

```
// Hopefully all can tell that this is just an example fn
function asyncServerRead(url) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    $.get(url, function(response) {
        deferred.resolve(response);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Now we have some functions that rely on responses of other functions

```
// This is how i say it has to be done
function doubleReadParadise(url) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    asyncServerRead(url).then(function(responseUrl) {
        asyncServerRead(responseUrl).then(function(response) {
            // .. most bestest operation ever ..
            deferred.resolve(response);
        });
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Now i wish this were not so.  I wish i could something like this

```
asyncServerRead(url).then(function(serverUrl) {
    return asyncServerRead(serverUrl);
}).then(function(response) {
    // .. most bestest operation ever ..
    return response;
});
```

Clearly that second version will not work.

Really what i am asking is with linear async operations, is it possible not to grow my very own pyramid of death?

Love,

Michael

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Q, it sort of seems like you're missing the point. The point of such deferred/async libraries is that you don't need nested callbacks. It creates a queue of callbacks, and invokes them one at a time, passing the response of each to the next call. Also in your last example, you seem to be using functions just for the sake of having them. For example, the callback you pass to the first `.then()` is doing nothing but passing on its argument to the actual function. Instead, you could just do `asyncServerRead(url).then(asyncServerRead)...` and have the same effect.

Comment: I think you may be unfamiliar with Q.  That is what i want.  but that is not how it works.  You should try it.

Comment: Well, yes... I am unfamiliar with Q as I stated. But yes, I've tried it, though using a `setTimeout` in place of the `$.get` call, and it works fine like that for me. Perhaps your example doesn't represent what you want to do. I'm familiar in general with queued approaches to async problems, and have written my own solutions.

Comment: What's wrong with `asyncServerRead(url).then(asyncServerRead).then(function(response){...}).done(successCallback, errorCallback);`